# How do I add reference lines in trellis dot plots in R in the lattice package

Tags: r, lattice, trellis

The following piece of code produces a trellis dot plot exactly as I would like it, but I would like to automatically add reference lines to the four panels.  I have tried searching for examples of code that will let me do this, but so far no luck.  Can anyone suggest a simple fix?

```
dotplot(region ~ productivity | los,
panel = panel.superpose,
group = month,
between = list(x=1, y=0),
index.cond = list(c(4,2,1,3)),
pch = 1:4, col = 1:4,
main = "Monthly Productivity by LoS by Region",
xlab = "Percent",
aspect = 1, 
key = list(space = "right",
    transparent = TRUE,
    points = list(pch = 1:4,
    col = 1:4),
    text = list(c("Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct"))))
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Functions `layer` and `panel.abline` from `latticeExtra`.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on where you'd like to have the reference lines. If you need to place them yourself, then use `panel.refline()`. (It's essentially a wrapper for `panel.abline()`, replacing that function's default stylings with ones more appropriate for reference lines.)

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars,
       panel = function(x,y,...){
           panel.refline(h = c(15,17))
           panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
       })
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you're just wanting a grid of reference lines à la **ggplot**, the `type=` argument offers a simple way to get one:

```
xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, type = c("g", "p")) ## "g"rid and "p"oints
```

[image]

Comment: That was embarrassingly easy.  Thanks very much.  Also, as a consequence of discovering the 'type' argument I also discovered that 'grid = TRUE' does the same thing.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Ah, good find, and thanks for mentioning it. Cheers.